# Relations: Completness implies reflexivity

Tags: relations

I just wanted to check if this proof works, as I couldn't find anything online. Thanks!

- A relation is **complete**: $(_xR_y) \cup (_yR_x)\; \forall x,y \in X $
- A relation is **reflexive**: $(_xR_x) \; \forall x \in X $

**Proof by contradiction that completeness implies reflexivity**

1. Let's assume R is complete, and *not* reflexive, i.e. $\exists \, x' \in X, s.t. \;  x'\not\mathrel{R} x' $
2. Then using completeness we must have $(x'Ry) \cup (yRx')$.
3. Setting  $x' = y$ we have our desired contradiction. As we must have $x'Rx'$

My only concern with this is that given the definition of completeness, $(_xR_y) \cup (_yR_x)\; \forall x,y \in X $, are we aloud to assume  $x = y$? Thanks!

Comment: Your proof is ok. And yes, $\forall x,y$ includes the case $y=x.$ [Direct proof](https://books.google.fr/books?id=3XjtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA71) is simpler than by contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. @Anne Bauval - I actually tried this initially, but struggled, perhaps because I wasn't sure I could equate x = y. Can you give me a clue. Thanks!

Comment: I gave a "clue" ($\forall$ is like that, nothing more) and a link (saying the same).

Comment: Yep, I've just realised. Now I know I can set x = y. It follows immediately, thanks! I'll post it as an answer. The link opens oddly for me, can you confirm the page you are referring too. Cheers!

Comment: Can we always set x = y in all definitions that state $\forall x,y \in X$

Comment: Yes, see my 1st comment. As for the link, it is Statistical Machine Learning: A Unified Framework (by Richard Golden) page 71 (if it does not work, insert this title + Google Books in a Google search)

Comment: Apologies @AnneBauval can you tell me which page number you are referring to, because the link sends me to sample pages that won't open. Thanks!

Comment: Ah the rest of that comment didn't load. Appreciate it, have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know that I can set $x = y$ in the definition of completeness. The answers follows Immediately.

Using **Completness** $(_xR_y) \cup (_yR_x)\; \forall x,y \in X $

Setting  $x = y$ we must have $(_xR_x) \cup (_yR_y)\; \forall x,y \in X $

Hence Reflexive. Thanks @Anne Bauval!